# Cannot make granting access to existing tables work

Tags: sql, postgresql, roles, rbac

I'm failing at adding a new DB role, that would have a `SELECT` privilege on tables from particular database.

My problem is that the role is not able to `SELECT` from a table in existing DB.

Here's my failing test case (written so it can safely be copy-pasted into a `/tmp/test.sh` and executed):

```
# --- cleanup objects, if any
psql -U postgres -c "REVOKE SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM db_reader"
psql -U postgres -c "REVOKE SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM db_reader"
psql -U postgres -c "REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA public FROM db_reader"
psql -U postgres -c "DROP ROLE IF EXISTS db_reader"
psql -U postgres -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS some_existing_db"
# --- test
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE some_existing_db"
psql -U postgres some_existing_db -c "CREATE TABLE cats (name varchar(10))"
psql -U postgres some_existing_db -c "INSERT INTO cats (name) VALUES ('a'), ('b')"
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE db_reader WITH login"
psql -U postgres -c 'GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO db_reader'
psql -U postgres -c 'GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO db_reader'
psql -U postgres -c 'GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO db_reader'
psql -U db_reader some_existing_db -c "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cats"
```

Looks like I'm missing something extremely, embarrassingly obvious here, as the **above fails with the following error**:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation cats
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing that databases are logically separated.

Your `GRANT` statements are executed in database `postgres` (if you do not specify a database name, `psql` will try to connect to a database with the same name as the database user).

Consequently, the effect of these grants is limited to the database to which you are connected.

You have to add `some_existing_db` to the `psql` invocations where you grant privileges to `db_reader`.

Comment: Thank you, Laurenz. I figured that myself moments after I posted the question, but left it for someone else to try to answer and explain why this was happening. It had never occurred to me that GRANTs are scoped to current context, e.g. the DB I'm issuing them from.

Comment: I just reviewed [`GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) page once again, and the fact that `GRANT`s are scoped to the DB they are being issued from is not stated. Do you happen to know where can I learn about this more? I was lucky to learn this by accident from an [email](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/83894A1821034948BA27FE4DAA47427928F7C29922%40apde03.APD.Satcom.Local) from PostgreSQL mailing list.

Comment: Funny, I couldn't find it in the documentation. Fact is that *all* SQL statements can only affect *global objects* or objects in the database to which you are connected.